# Is there any way to make Twitter Bootstrap buttons the same height across browser when applied to a submit button?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, button

Someone here been using Twitter Bootstrap, I'm trying to fix a few things, I do not know much about Bootstrap.

Anyways, he has applied the twitter bootstrap button classes/styles to the submit buttons but the heights are different in Firefox vs Chrome.

Using a CMS, no control over HTML.

Any workarounds?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an excerpt from [the "Button tags" section of the documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons-tags):

> #### Cross-browser rendering
>
> As a best practice, **we highly recommend using the `<button>` element
>   whenever possible** to ensure matching cross-browser rendering.
>
> Among other things, there's [a Firefox
>   bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=697451) that
>   prevents us from setting the `line-height` of `<input>`-based buttons,
>   causing them to not exactly match the height of other buttons on
>   Firefox.

Comment: cheers mate, but I should have mentioned that we are working with a CMS here and it uses input[type="submit"] for buttons. we cannot change this code. srry should have mentioned that :(